# How to correctly annotate component props that can accept Component or string as html tag?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to correctly annotate component props that accept `Component` or string as html tag?

For example, I have a component that can take custom Component (includes html tag like `div`, `p` etc.). It's written like this:

```
interface MyComponentProps<T> {
    comp: React.ComponentType<T>
}

function MyComponent<T>({ comp: Component }: MyComponentProps<T>) {
  return <Component />
}
```

Typescript doesn't complaint if I pass another component as `comp` props to `MyComponent` like this:

```
function Wrapper() {
    return <div />
}

function render() {
    return <MyComponent comp={Wrapper} />
}
```

But, when I pass standard html tag like this:

```
function render() {
  return <MyComponent comp="div"/>
}
```

typescript compiler complaints:

```
Type '{ comp: "div"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MyComponentProps<{}>'.
  Type '{ comp: "div"; }' is not assignable to type 'MyComponentProps<{}>'.
    Types of property 'comp' are incompatible.
      Type '"div"' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
```

So, how can I annotate a component like `MyComponent` without using `any` type?

Comment: You can use union types as described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: union type with string clearly doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Dragomir - union types are the way to go. The code below compiles just fine.

```
interface MyComponentProps<T>
{
    comp: React.ComponentType<T> | string;
}

function MyComponent<T>({ comp: Component }: MyComponentProps<T>)
{
    return <Component />;
}

function render()
{
    return <MyComponent comp={Wrapper}/>;
}

function render2()
{
    return <MyComponent comp="div"/>;
}
```

Comment: `React.ReactElement` is what returned from render function. What I need to pass to props is not `ReactElement` but `ReactComponent`.

Comment: Show example of what you want to pass as value to `comp` property

Comment: Edited with how I pass a `Component` to `MyComponent`

Comment: Then leave its declaration as it was: `comp: React.ComponentType<T> | string;` in the example I gave - it compiles just fine.

Comment: It works, thanks. And sorry, my real code has `?` in the field with `strict` option in `compilerOptions`. But, your answer is a bit misleading. Could you update it before I accept?